# nodejs Error: write Unknown system errno 5 at errnoException (net.js:642:11) at Object.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:480:18)

Tags: node.js

I have developed a TCP server application based on nodes, but this app crashes after a while, as soon as someone connects and sends the data on the port, I took a stack trace using [winston](/questions/tagged/winston):

```
{
    "process": {
        "pid": 28214,
        "uid": 0,
        "gid": 0,
        "cwd": "/home/ec2-user",
        "execPath": "/home/ec2-                user/node/out/Release/node",
        "version": "v0.6.10",
        "argv": [
            "node",
            "/home/ec2-user/Node_TcpServer.js"
        ],
        "memoryUsage": {
            "rss": 12144640,
            "heapTotal": 5274304,
            "heapUsed": 3318328
        }
    },
    "os": {
        "loadavg": [
            0.0029296875,
            0.0146484375,
            0.04541015625
        ],
        "uptime": 779924.506942403
    },
    "trace": [
        {
            "column": 11,
            "file": "net.js",
            "function": "errnoException",
            "line": 642,
            "method": null,
            "native": false
        },
        {
            "column": 18,
            "file": "[as oncomplete] (net.js",
            "function": "Object.afterWrite",
            "line": 480,
            "method": "afterWrite",
            "native": false
        }
    ],
    "stack": [
        "Error: write Unknown system errno 5",
        "    at errnoException (net.js:642:11)",
        "    at Object.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:480:18)"
    ],
    "level": "error",
    "message": "uncaughtException"
}

{"process":{"pid":28214,"uid":0,"gid":0,"cwd":"/home/ec2-user","execPath":"/home/ec2-user/node/out/Release/node","version":"v0.6.10","argv":["node","/home/ec2-user/Node_TcpServer.js"],"memoryUsage":{"rss":12230656,"heapTotal":5274304,"heapUsed":3470656}},"os":{"loadavg":[0.0029296875,0.0146484375,0.04541015625],"uptime":779924.509452039},"trace":[{"column":11,"file":"net.js","function":"errnoException","line":642,"method":null,"native":false},{"column":18,"file":"[as oncomplete] (net.js","function":"Object.afterWrite","line":480,"method":"afterWrite","native":false}],"stack":["Error: write Unknown system errno 5","    at errnoException (net.js:642:11)","    at Object.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:480:18)"],"level":"error","message":"uncaughtException"} "
```

Comment: Do you have a question? Have you started looking at the code path referenced in the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the code failed to write the socket. Maybe a client disconnected.

You should listen to the ['error' event](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_event_error) to catch the exception.